# Task Approve/Reject Permission

Tags: workflow, permissions, tasks

There are 3 participants in the workflow. They can approve/reject the task of the current item. I want every participant to be able to approve/reject only their own tasks, not other participants.

For example:
When Ece approve the task, the task assign to Joe. But Ece sees the task assigned to him and can approve/reject Joe's task. I don't want it. I want Ece not to be able to approve/reject other tasks. 
How can I make it happen? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you please mention the workflow type like OOB or sharePoint Designer or custom VS workflow?

Comment: Sharepoint Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First i selected start approval process action then Go to Approval workflow process settings, in that screen under the settings category check the General settings Check box.

Comment: Now when I press approve/reject it keeps saying Sorry this site doesn't shared with you.

Comment: Administration > System Settings > Managed Services on Server.  I stopped the Distributed Cache then started again.  Then did the same thing from the server by going to Administrative Tools > AppFabric Caching Service -- I stopped and restarted that one

Comment: Ok now it works. But when one participant reject it, workflow doesn't finish, it continues to assign task to next participates.

Comment: Change the default Approval workflow action in the SP Designer. if item is approved is equal to no then you add stop workflow action.

Comment: Is it same with complete workflow ?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is only applies to 2010 workflow types. If you have a SharePoint 2013 type WF this setting is completely missing!

Comment: yes, it is missing!