# Users can see (and approve!) each other's tasks

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions, tasks, visual-studio-2012

Is there a quick and easy way to prevent users from seeing and approving each other's tasks?
I do NOT want to create a task list per user and would like to avoid setting up item level permissions / event receivers.

MSDN forums suggest [turning on view filters and filter by [ME]](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/db4f1584-5dc4-4cbc-bfe4-53e71c288b27/how-to-restrict-users-to-see-others-tasks-workflows-approval-processes-in-sp2013-foundation?forum=sharepointgeneral). Which I think is a bit silly, considering that users can create personal views or use other techniques to go around it.

In SharePoint designer workflows, there is this option called ["Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71073/task-approve-reject-permission) (which I haven't tried, but I would assume provides the functionality I need). This is a Visual Studio, SharePoint 2013 workflow however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks don't have any security wrapped around them by default so this isn't unexpected. Item level permissions is one option (which would require you to do some extra work within your workflow) or to use the other option you referenced in your last para. Since you are using VS to build your workflow though, you'll have to implement this manually (no, not fun).

Comment: But Andrew is there any way to do it SharePoint Designer 2013

Comment: Yup, just more work as you'd have to do it manually using the REST API.

Comment: @AndrewConnell So we have to check on the task page maybe whether the logged in user is assigned to the task?